# Java to C#: code computing from document hash

Tags: c#, algorithm, sha256

I have Java code example, of how verification code should be computed. And I have to convert Java code to C#.

First of all, code is computed as:

```
integer(SHA256(hash)[-2: -1]) mod 10000
```

Where  we take SHA256 result, extract 2 rightmost bytes from it, interpret them as big-endian unsigned integer and take the last 4 digits in decimal for display.

Java code:

```
public static String calculate(byte[] documentHash) {
    byte[] digest = DigestCalculator.calculateDigest(documentHash, HashType.SHA256);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(digest);
    int shortBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE; // Short.BYTES in java 8
    int rightMostBytesIndex = byteBuffer.limit() - shortBytes;
    short twoRightmostBytes = byteBuffer.getShort(rightMostBytesIndex);
    int positiveInteger = ((int) twoRightmostBytes) & 0xffff;
    String code = String.valueOf(positiveInteger);
    String paddedCode = "0000" + code;
    return paddedCode.substring(code.length());
  }

public static byte[] calculateDigest(byte[] dataToDigest, HashType hashType) {
    String algorithmName = hashType.getAlgorithmName();
    return DigestUtils.getDigest(algorithmName).digest(dataToDigest);
  }
```

So int C# from Base64 string: 
 `2afAxT+nH5qNYrfM+D7F6cKAaCKLLA23pj8ro3SksqwsdwmC3xTndKJotewzu7HlDy/DiqgkR+HXBiA0sW1x0Q==`

should compute code equal to: `3676`

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetCode("2afAxT+nH5qNYrfM+D7F6cKAaCKLLA23pj8ro3SksqwsdwmC3xTndKJotewzu7HlDy/DiqgkR+HXBiA0sW1x0Q=="));
    }


    public static string GetCode(string str)
    {
        var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create();
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
        var last2 = hash[^2..];
        var intVal = ((int) last2[0]) * 0x0100 + ((int) last2[1]);
        var digits = intVal % 10000;
        return $"{digits:0000}";            
    }
}
```

Comment: Users of VS2017 and earlier (maybe down to VS2013) can replace the line `var last2 = hash[^2..];` with `var last2 = hash.Skip(hash.Length - 2).ToArray();`.